# Posting to application timeline as a user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-timeline

I need to post status, links, pictures to application time line on the behalf of user. Only available option for me to update application page using "/PAGE_NAME/feed" with manage_page permission.

I have successfully posted status using above graph path. But Facebook is showing/tracking these status, links as application posts instead of user's activity.

Instead of showing user's name in post details, it is showing application name. There is no option to distinguish user posts.

Is there any option to post application wall/time line on the behalf of user? Is it a bug in facebook not detecting user's access token?

Can any one answer me? I hope my question is clear to all and if needed I could provide an explanation for novice users.

Comment: Why are you posting to the app, if you really want the post to go to the app’s _page_? Post to the latter instead.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your response. I can post to application page using graph path "APP_PAGE_ID/feed", but I will require manage_page permission and valid page access token. But former should work. If no other solution exist, I should fallback to the latter.

Comment: Why I'm being down voted? APP_ID/feed was working previously but not now. According to facebook documentation APP_ID/feed will be posted to application profile page and I'm not doing anything wrong here with their API. I hope that my question is clear and it contain research value. Please do the needful

Comment: The application profile pages were removed over a year ago, there's nowhere for a post to `/<APP ID>/feed` to actually go

Comment: But facebook still accepting post /<APP ID>/feed and its documentation still active. I need to update app page on the behalf of user. I have tried using /<APP PAGE NAME>/feed and manage_page permission. All posts were tracking on the behalf of application but not the user. Instead of showing user's activity, facebook is showing application activity.

Comment: Oh, i didn't realise it was still in the documentation, i'll remove it now, thanks!

Comment: Can we rely on your documentation? I didn't get my answer, but   helped to report one documentation bug. Still my question down voted for -1. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we try to post status, Facebook will consider as application status update.  ie. Posting with message parameter. If we try to post with link, picture, facebook is accepting as user's post.

Now it is working correctly. There is no change in approach. Thanks for all who down voted without realizing the question.

POST "message" : "USER MESSAGE" => App status update (User will not be tracked)

POST "message" : "USER MESSAGE","link": "LINK" => User post update on time line (User name will be tracked)

I hope this will help some one. Please check comments for my question too.